# time data does not match format

Tags: python, datetime

I get the following error:

```
time data '07/28/2014 18:54:55.099000' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

But I cannot see what parameter is wrong in `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f` ?

This is the code I use.

```
from datetime import datetime
time_value = datetime.strptime(csv_line[0] + '000', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

I have added and removed the `000` but I get the same error.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You have the month and day swapped:

```
'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

`28` will never fit in the range for the `%m` month parameter otherwise.

With `%m` and `%d` in the correct order parsing works:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('07/28/2014 18:54:55.099000', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 28, 18, 54, 55, 99000)
```

You don't need to add `'000'`; `%f` can parse shorter numbers correctly:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('07/28/2014 18:54:55.099', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 28, 18, 54, 55, 99000)
```

Answer (score 108):

While the above answer is 100% helpful and correct, I'd like to add the following since only a combination of the above answer and reading through the pandas doc helped me:

### **2-digit / 4-digit year**

It is noteworthy, that in order to parse through a 2-digit year, e.g. '90' rather than '1990', a `%y` is required instead of a `%Y`.

### **Infer the datetime automatically**

If parsing with a pre-defined format still doesn't work for you, try using the flag `infer_datetime_format=True`, for example:

```
yields_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(yields_df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Be advised that this solution is slower than using a pre-defined format.

Comment: This is a great solution for the endless date format issues, thanks @whiletrue !

Comment: Thanks for the %Y tip, solved my problem

Answer (score 24):

No need to use datetime library. Using the dateutil library there is no need of any format:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> s= '25 April, 2020, 2:50, pm, IST'
>>> parser.parse(s)
datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 25, 14, 50)
```

Comment: For me it gives an UnknownTimezoneWarning in Python 3.7 with IST. It works with CET.

Comment: Just this `from dateutil import parser;parser.parse('25 April, 2020, 2:50, pm, IST')`, I use the python3-dateutil 2.7.3-3 package in Debian 10. I haven't checked the latest version with pip.

Comment: Well answered. This is the best approach without mentioning the format. +1 for that.

Comment: Simple solution, worked perfectly. I was struggling with a client that would sometimes send me xx:xx or xx:xx:xx for time and I would get errors.

Comment: Using parser to automatically parse the datetime string to datetime is effortless, indeed. However, I found it's not perfect and **error prone**. For example, if you try this example, you will found it did in the **wrong** way:    `parser.parse("2023:03:24 18:00:23")`       it gives you   `datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 11, 18, 0, 23)`, which is clearly wrong! So be attention with using it.

Answer (score 6):

I had a case where solution was hard to figure out. This is not exactly relevant to particular question, but might help someone looking to solve a case with same error message when strptime is fed with timezone information. In my case, the reason for throwing

**ValueError: time data '2016-02-28T08:27:16.000-07:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'**

was presence of last colon in the timezone part. While in some locales (Russian one, for example) code was able to execute well, in another (English one) it was failing. Removing the last colon helped remedy my situation.

Comment: Just had the same issue. The dash you see is a minus sign, and in the western hemisphere, where timezones are behind GTM, you will see that. In the rest of the world, you will see a plus sign. Python 3.6 suffered from this issue, while Python 3.8 seems to have a fix for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999230/how-to-parse-timezone-with-colon covers this issue

Answer (score 3):

To compare date time, you can try this. Datetime format can be changed

```
from datetime import datetime

>>> a = datetime.strptime("10/12/2013", "%m/%d/%Y")
>>> b = datetime.strptime("10/15/2013", "%m/%d/%Y")
>>> a>b
False
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same error but with slightly different format and root-cause, and since this is the first Q&A that pops up when you search for "time data does not match format", I thought I'd leave the mistake I made for future viewers:

My initial code:

```
start = datetime.strptime('05-SEP-19 00.00.00.000 AM', '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
```

Where I used `%I` to parse the hours and `%p` to parse 'AM/PM'.

The error:

> ValueError: time data '05-SEP-19 00.00.00.000000 AM' does not match format '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p'

I was going through the [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) and finally realized in 12-hour format `%I`, there is no 00... once I changed `00.00.00` to `12.00.00`, the problem was resolved.

So it's either 01-12 using `%I` with `%p`, or 00-23 using `%H`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error -

```
time data '01-07-2020' does not match format '%d%m%Y' (match)
```

I didn't know that I have to use a hyphen in the format parameter. This worked for me -

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same error, **time data '09/24/1997' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y'**

If your date is using **/** then also use **/** in your format, for example

**'09/24/1997'** => **'%m/%d/%Y'** using dashes will give you that error.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say we have datetime format string form with below format:

```
2018-01-31T09:24:31.488670+00:00
```

We can convert this given datetime str to datetime object

```
import datetime 
        
DatetImeObj = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-01-31T09:24:31.488670+00:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

This will return datetime format with result:

```
2018-01-31 09:24:31.488670+00:00
```

Now if you want to convert this date time in any format you can use any datetime function

```
finalDateTime = Datetime.datetime.strftime(DatetImeObj , ‘%Y-%m-%d %H:%M’)
```

output:

```
2018-01-31 09:24
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the capital "Y" if in case you are using the small "y"

for example:

```
Input: '2022-10-05 15:22:39'
datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: But the author clearly uses capital Y.

Answer (score -5):

You have to just remove "/" from the String and put "," in it .. Boom

See the following code:

```
import datetime as dt
str = '01,01,2017'
datetime_value = dt.datetime.strptime(str,'%d,%m,%Y')
print(datetime_value) # prints: 2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stackoverflow. With your suggestion, you modify both the input string, and also the format to be parsed in the input string. As such, I believe it does not answer the question.