# Convert string into datetime with timezone in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, datetime, google-calendar-api

How to properly use strptime to convert string data from Google Calendar API to datetime object?

Here are two working cases:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

obj = datetime.strptime('2018-03-01T12:00:00+01:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+01:00')
print(obj)   # 2018-03-01 12:00:00

obj = datetime.strptime('2018-03-01T12:00:00+0100', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z') 
print(obj)   # 2018-03-01 12:00:00+01:00
```

And one where I have problem.

```
obj = datetime.strptime('2018-03-01T12:00:00+01:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
print(obj)   # ERROR
```

Why according to documentation `%z` does not match `+01:00` with colon? But only `+0100` without colon?

Is there any way to resolve this problem using `datetime`?

Comment: I can't explain *why* `datetime` seems to have this inconsistency. But have you considered using `dateutil.parser.parse`? This seems to have all your varieties covered.

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999230/parsing-timezone-with-colon

Comment: @wokadakow, I added a solution using `dateutil` to the question linked by @LaurentH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ISO Time (ISO 8601) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150739/iso-time-iso-8601-in-python)