# How would I convert this string '2022-07-07T10:30:00-07:00' into datetime obj in python?

Tags: python, datetime, iso8601

I am having trouble converting this string '2022-07-07T10:30:00-07:00' to a datetime object in order to then extract the date and time separately.

I have tried the following code:

```
 date_time  =  '2022-07-07T10:30:00-07:00'
 d1 = datetime.strptime(date_time,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

However,I get  the following error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: -07:00
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I think the problem is with the `07:00` at the end of your `date_time` variable. I'm not an expert in datetime zones format, but I guess `07:00` does not indicate anything.

Comment: That's presumably supposed to be a timezone offset, but it's not formatted correctly. It should be `-0700`, and then you can use the `%Z` format to parse it.

Comment: `%z` (lower case) will parse it, even with a colon, as of Python 3.7.  There is a [note 6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20strptime#technical-detail)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse timezone with colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999230/how-to-parse-timezone-with-colon)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final `-7:00` is a timezone offset in hours and minutes.  `%z` can be used to parse it into a timezone-aware `datetime` object:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_time  =  '2022-07-07T10:30:00-07:00'
d1 = datetime.strptime(date_time,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
print(repr(d1))
print(d1)
```

Output:

```py
datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 7, 10, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=61200)))
2022-07-07 10:30:00-07:00
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20strptime#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

> *Changed in version 3.7*: When the `%z` directive is provided to the `strptime()` method, the UTC offsets can have a colon as a separator between hours, minutes and seconds. For example, '+01:00:00' will be parsed as an offset of one hour. In addition, providing 'Z' is identical to '+00:00'.

Comment: This also works on WSL Ubuntu and on Raspbian Linux

Comment: Note: since Python 3.7, there is [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)