# How does Python handle time conversions?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

Recently I have been working on a time series data set and have written a script to automate some plotting. Using the pd.to_datetime function (provided with a specific format), I assumed would automatically convert every time entry to the appropriate format.

```
The raw data follows this format:
%d/%m/%YYYY HH:MM (HH:MM is irrelevant in this case so don't worry about it as we are only interested in the daily average)
```

However, it seems Python intermittently changes the 'raw timestamps' and changes the format to:
%d-%m-%YYYY

Why is this the case and how can I make sure Python doesn't do this?

I have received the below error and struggle to work out why this is the case.
I have looked at the following SO but I don't have the same issue.
[time data does not match format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015711/time-data-does-not-match-format)

The data itself is provided in the following CSV and is all in the %d/%m/%Y format.

[image: Error message]

My code for my function is attached in case there are any errors with how I've converted the timestamps.

```
def plotFunction(dataframe):
    for i in wellNames:
        my_list = dataframe["Date"].values
        DatesRev = []

        for j in my_list:
            a=j[0:10]
            DatesRev.append(a)
        #We now need to re-add the dates to our data frame
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data= DatesRev)
        df2.columns = ["DatesRev"]
        dataframe["DatesRev"] = df2["DatesRev"]
#         print (dataframe)
#         #df2= pd.DataFrame(DatesRev) 
#         #df2.columns = ['DatesRev']    
#         #dataframe['DatesRev'] = df2['DatesRev']
        wellID = dataframe[dataframe['Well']==i]
        wellID['DatesRev'] = pd.to_datetime(wellID['DatesRev'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
        print (i)
#         ax = wellID.set_index('DatesRev').plot()
#         xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y')
#         ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
#         plt.xticks(rotation=90)
#         ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.04,1), loc="upper left")
#         plt.title(i)
#         plt.show()
#         plt.savefig(i + ".jpg", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: the problem is that python does not recognize `/` very well. I came across this problem myself. Dashes are what it recognizes the best. If I may suggest, try to keep the `-` formatting.

Comment: @JulianRachman - Interesting! I wasn't aware of that. The data will always be coming in this type of format so I will have to get used to this regardless. Python's pretty robust at handling special 'characters' so '/' shouldn't really be a hindrance. There has to be a robust solution for this - I'm certain of it. but I'll take your point into consideration. :)

Comment: Ya it is an interesting thing but it's just Python doing Python things. Let me know if it works. I will post an answer.

Comment: Try “%s/%s/%s”  %(d, m, Y)

Comment: @mikey - this did not work either unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that python does not recognize `/` very well. I came across this problem myself. Dashes are what it recognizes the best. If I may suggest, try to keep the `-` formatting. It is just Python being Python. :P

In `wellID['DatesRev']`, change `format='%d/%m/%Y'` to `format='%d-%m-%Y'` and that should possibly fix your problem.

Comment: Hi Julian - I don't think this would solve the issue as inherently, it seems Python it self is changing the dates '/' to '-' on a random basis. I tried it anyway and it didn't work.

Comment: hmm, so sometimes it works and sometimes it does not?

Comment: Yes, it is inconsistent. This is why I am trying to understand why this is the case.

Comment: have a look at this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: I've managed to resolve it via another means. I'll post up an answer tomorrow regarding this :)
Thanks for your assistance anyway!