# Error Python: time data 'Oct 22 2019 12:58:45:196AM' does not match format '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S:%f%p' (match)

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime-format

I'm trying to datetime a column of a dataframe. But I skip this mistake, I read the documentation of datetime and I don't understand what the problem is.

```
datetime.strptime('Oct 22 2019 12:58:45:196AM', '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S:%f%p')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [time data does not match format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015711/time-data-does-not-match-format)

Comment: It works under python 3.7.  What is the python version that you are using?

Comment: Im using python 3.6.5

Comment: If i use: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_us') before, works. But if i try to use pd.to_datetime(df1[f], '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S:%f%p').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') dont work

Answer (score 0):

```
USE this one there is no need to any format
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> s= '25 April, 2020, 2:50, pm, IST'
>>> parser.parse(s)
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 25, 14, 50)
```

Comment: This isn't really solving the problem. We don't know where the input will be coming from and should not change it (in not trivial ways) just like that.