# Parsing to Datetime causing ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have flight data stored in a csv including for example the scheduled departure in the form 0005 (for 00:05 am). Thus in order to work with the data, I need to parse it into datetimeformat - here: "%H%M". Can you explain why it isn´t working?
Thanlls for your help!!!

```
df['SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'], format="%H%M")
```

ValueError: time data '5' does not match format '%H%M' (match)

Comment: You might check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015711/time-data-does-not-match-format

Comment: The error message indicates that the value is `5`, not `0005`. What's the dtype of the column?

Comment: I guess there is a value in this DateTime column that has a value of "5" which doesn't fit the format you specified. one solution you can do is set the error parameter as coerce. See doc https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: How are you reading the CSV file into pandas df? Most likely your SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE column is converted to integers by default and thus 0005 turns into 5

Comment: The dtype is int64

Comment: ```df = pd.read_csv('./Originaldata/flights.csv', sep=',', usecols=['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'])``` @Karol Zak

Comment: @MartinMüller yep, you need to specify dtype for 'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE' column otherwise it's converted to integer. I added my answer with code that should fix it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with how you are reading the CSV with pandas into dataframe. I guess your SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE column gets auto converted to integer type and thus `0005` becomes just `5`

```py
# reading CSV "as is" with autoconvertion of types
pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)
```

[image]

```py
# reading CSV with forcing data type for specific columns
pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None, dtype={2:str})
```

[image]

So in your case your `read_csv` function should look somewhat like this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
  './Originaldata/flights.csv',
  sep=',',
  usecols=['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'],
  dtype={'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE':str}
)
```